# C++ setting up a callback function

Tags: c++, callback

I am working at a program which runs a custom webserver that should output some active HTML content:

```
// This is the webserver library...
class myWebServer
{
public:
    myWebServer() {}
    ~myWebServer() {}

    // ...

    void sendPageToClient()
    {
        // ... "client" is the TCP socket
        // ... "html" should contain the output of myMainProgram::ProcessASP

        client->send(html);
    }

    void runServer()
    {
        while (1)
        {
            // listens to TCP socket
            client->listen();

            // receive query from browser
            // send HTML using sendPageToClient()
            // ...
            sendPageToClient();
        }
    }
};


// This is the main program class...
class myMainProgram
{
public:
    myMainProgram() {}
    ~myMainProgram() {}

    // ...

    string ProcessASP(string query)
    {
        return
        "<html>The query string you have passed contains:<br>"
        + query +
        "</html>";
    }

    void runProgram()
    {
        // do something
    }
};


// This is a multi-threaded application
void main()
{
    myMainProgram   myProgram;
    myWebServer myServer;

    myProgram.runProgram();
    myServer.runServer();
};
```

How can I set up a callback function that from the class `myWebServer` calls `myMainProgram::ProcessASP` passing parameters and receiving its output?

Comment: You might want to read about [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use a [`std::function<std::string(std::string)>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

```
class myWebServer {
    // not really a "callback"?
    std::function<std::string(std::string)> callback;

public:
    template <typename F>
    void setCallback(F&& f) { callback = std::forward<F>(f); }

    void runServer() {
      // ...
      std::string foo = callback("hello");
      // do something with foo
    }
};
```

And then, you can do:

```
myServer.setCallback([&](std::string query){
    return myProgram.ProcessASP(query);
});
```

Comment: Yes, that indeed works! Can you please explain why you're saying that it's not really a callback?

Comment: @MarkMiles I think of a callback as like "ok, I got some data, now you go do something with it." This is more of a "I need to ask you for something" - so it's not *quite* the same thing.